# Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView not working properly for chart if there are hidden rows/column in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vba, charts, vsto

On click of button, I want to scroll in the worksheet to the place where I've chart.

Below method works perfectly if sheet doesn't have any hidden rows/columns:

```
Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView(chart.ChartArea.Left, chart.ChartArea.Top, chart.ChartArea.Width, chart.ChartArea.Height,true);
//where chart is my Excel.Chart object
```

However, if there are hidden rows and columns in worksheet, the method scrolls at wrong location.

Can someone please help me with the appropriate way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Chart.Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.visible) property which returns or sets an `XlSheetVisibility` value that determines whether the object is visible. So, before calling the [Window.ScrollIntoView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Window.ScrollIntoView) method you can be sure it is visible and method call makes sense.

Comment: The chart is visible. The problem occurs if I have Excel sheet with freeze pane. In such case, Scrollintoview takes me to a different location.